# How to update/replace php script on server

Tags: php

I am working on update feature for a CMS. But I stuck on this. The scenario is user will able to upload a zip file, the updater script will extract it and replace the old one.

I have a problem with replacing, I've done the following

```
<?php rename($old, $new);
```

I always get "Permission Denied"

using `ftp_rename`:

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect($host);
ftp_login($conn, 'user', 'pass');
ftp_rename($conn, $src, $dest);
```

I always get

> Warning: ftp_rename(): Rename Failed. on....

Is there a proper way to do this ? thanks.

---

Comment: I think you'd come across far less problems by using a database driven CMS rather than file based

Comment: Hi @scrowler thanks, the cms is database driven, but it's for updating the whole cms.

Comment: Do you mean replacing your source code like an "upgrade" sort of procedure? Regardless, the reason you won't be allowed to do this is because the user that your web server (Apache?) is running as may not actually have permission to modify the files. You might need to allow the web server user to modify files in a chown/chmod fashion

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your linux distro, php actually executes command as a specific user. Check your apache (or whatever server you are using) settings and put the permission accordingly

For example in apache, it is set

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

You can then change that upload folder to be owned by www-data

For more information you can read this useful discussion
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30879/what-user-should-apache-and-php-be-running-as-what-permissions-should-var-www